# How do I switch back to python2 after Anaconda set python3 as the default?

Tags: python3, python-2.7, anaconda

Recently, I installed [Anaconda3-2.5.0-Linux-x86_64.sh](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/) on my 15.04 and ended up with this!

```
:~$ python --version
Python 3.5.1 :: Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)

:~$ python2 --version
Python 2.7.9

:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.1 :: Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)
```

During the last moments of installation, I did enter something as `yes` in hurry, and I suppose it had to do something with this. (Ok, my fault, I should have handled that carefully, but I need help now, not criticism).

[image: Screenshot]

AFAIK this is definitely going to break other programs. What do I do now?

---

What I think could work.

Can this be done using aliases?

```
alias python=python2
```

But I ain't sure.

Comment: Yes. use `alias python=python2`

Comment: *AFAIK this is definitely going to break other programs.* What makes you think so? If Anaconda sets Python 3 as the default, it's probably for a reason.

Comment: I already have ruined one of my projects that was written for 2.x, and converting default to 3.x is not encouraged especially since many packages work on 2.x!

Comment: This is when you are very glad that you took the professional approach and had a clone of your pre-install boot drive to prevent this from becoming a big time-waster.  Please see my answer below.  I think your install method caused the glitch.  So if this happened to me I would revert and retry.  Total time would be less than a day to figure out whether it is viable.  In my case, as you can see, I am at the end of verifications so can now progress to see if this is worth the effort in the first place.  Took a couple days to make sure it hadn't caused a problem, and research work is on track.

Comment: as for specifying the version of Python, be sure you know exactly the ripple effect this can have throughout your whole system.  Unless you are just playing, it will really require a full verification process if you change the targets of the default `which python` shebang results.  It takes just a bit of time up front to prevent later discovering that you have painted yourself into the corner of needing to rewrite some of your utilities.  Best is to leave things working with the defaults unless you have a lot of time on your hands.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I went through the installation in a VM, and the following happend.

1. The installer asks for an install location. Default is `/home/myuser/anaconda3`.
2. At the end you'll be asked

   ```
   Python 3.5.1 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
   creating default environment...
   installation finished.
   Do you wish the installer to prepend the Anaconda3 install location
   to PATH in your /home/myuser/.bashrc ? [yes|no]
   [no] >>> yes

   Prepending PATH=/home/myuser/anaconda3/bin to PATH in /home/myuser/.bashrc
   A backup will be made to: /home/myuser/.bashrc-anaconda3.bak
   ```

To restore the old behavior, go to your home directory and do

```
mv .bashrc-anaconda3.bak .bashrc
```

then start a new shell.

As you suggest, you could `alias python=python2`, but I find that a bit weird.
I would

1. Restore the original `.bashrc`
2. Create (if it does not exist) `~/bin`
3. Link `ln -s ~/anaconda3/bin/python3 ~/bin/python3`
4. [Prepend `$HOME/bin` to `$PATH`](Should already be set by default by `~/.profile`)
5. Relogin.

That way, calling `python3` will start the one from Anaconda.

---

An important point is, that the original `/usr/bin/python` is still there, and still points to `python2.7`. The ramifications of having `python->python3` in your path depend on how a specific script is called.

If the shebang `#!/usr/bin/python` is used, like it probably is in all executables that ship with Ubuntu, nothing will change. 
On the other hand, for better portability `#!/usr/bin/env python` is sometimes used, which will now cause `python3.5` to be called.

Comment: "4. Prepend $HOME/bin to $PATH" .. already done by default `~/.profile` - just a relogin is needed after creating `~/bin`.

Comment: @muru That's true, thanks. Added to the answer.

Comment: okay, that worked, thanks! Just to put this into notice, that I had python 3.4.3 also installed previously (and pip and pip3 were both associated with it), now I have 2.7, 3.4, 3.5. Now I'm gonna re-install pip to point it to 3.5!

Comment: Anaconda comes with its own package manager called conda. It also manages virtual environments. I use that to install packages instead of pip.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994716/what-is-the-difference-between-pip-and-conda

Comment: Avoiding `pip` to me is a red flag that simply reinforces the need to have a clone of my boot drive before making major changes.  Then you are truly bullet-proof.  You can even go to root and do `rm -rf *` and know your system will survive.  Hard drives are commodities.  Don't get too enamored with any one of them.  They are like light bulbs, if you remember those:  "whenever your turn one on, be ready to say goodbye"

Answer (score 7):

Good answer here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405561/how-to-install-2-anacondas-python-2-7-and-3-4-on-mac-os-10-9

```
conda create -n python2 python=2.7 anaconda
```

then, to switch:

```
source activate python2
```

Comment: If you need this you could very well have much deeper problems.  If your system is important, do a full verification of any Python-dependent commands and/or utilities.    Fair warning.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is looking to change their python default version back to 2.7 after messing it up(by changing default one to: anaconda or python 3) and ending up with non-functional software, just follow this link: [Link with instructions to change default python version.](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux)

Comment: If a system change goes awry, be sure you can roll it back.  Make sure you have good system image backups so any major changes can be reversed quickly if they don't go as you plan.  Think professional.  If you use amateur techniques then you can't expect professional results.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me but for Miniconda, it should also work for Anaconda but please correct me if I'm wrong.

First get your **$PATH** variable:

```
echo $PATH
```

It will probably look like this (miniconda path before everything else):

```
/home/your_user/miniconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Copy that path to the bottom of your **~/.bashrc** file, but with Miniconda at the end instead of the beginning of the path like so:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/your_user/miniconda3/bin"
```

The system will look for programs at the start of the **$PATH** variable before the miniconda3/bin folder.

It should restore the versions for previous programs you had like python.

Starting in [Conda 4.4, they changed the code](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#440-2017-12-20) added to ~/.bashrc. Now, to achieve the same thing, edit ~/.bashrc and comment out the line below like so to prevent the base layer (base environment) from activating in every terminal. No need to touch any other part of the new additions. I am uncertain what significance `CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false` has, but haven't run into any issues so far.

```
   # CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
```

And while you won't see the conda folder in the path anymore, the `conda` command will still run fine, and your original `python`, `python3`, and `pipenv` commands will as well.

Comment: Upvote because I think you are correct.  This is good to have in the database.  However, can I please ask that you be a tad more specific as to version numbers of the software involved?

Comment: Thank you, and I don't really think that the program version matters, this should always work. At the time my installer was at the following version however: Miniconda3 4.3.14. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer, and it may or may not be the actual specific answer to what you have done to your own system.

However, I am in a similar situation and had the very same concern.

**I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Python 2.7.12, and just recently installed Anaconda.**

So now, when I go to the command line and type `python` it still goes to my Python2 installation.

Confirmed by this sequesnce:

```
$which python
/usr/bin/python     <  Catch-all for max compatibility
$python
Python 2.7.12 . . etc
```

So in my case, `anaconda` does NOT cause any problem with my default Python2 shebangs.

**Ultimately, that is the question.**

When you ask the system `which python` you can trust that to be correct string to use in the first line of your command-line style Python programs.

In my situation, all my same Python command-line script files continue to execute just fine.

I tend to write Python in a 3-compatible mode.  Such as using parentheses around my print statements.  But I am actively resisting a major change to the system that might cause hard-fought Python 2 programs to encounter glitches.  Python 3 sounds great but unnecessary for my needs.  Python 2 is an amazing language.

My computing environment does not allow me to go back and re-engineer past processes that have been tuned to work correctly without taking a mjor time hit since I would have to go back and figure out where I used it in the first place.

---

Bottom line for me:  Upon install `anaconda` for future use, I have not had any speed bumps nor problems.

---

That is the point where I am in the process...   Just finished re-certifying all the past software.

---

Next step is to actually use some of the cool stuff that is promised in the package.

---

**So, I must suspect that other simply installing `anaconda` there must be more to your situation.**

From my experience it is not a problem at all.

Comment: FYI, I have a complete Scientific workstation, working on solar dynamics.  Also about ephemerals and satellite interactions.  It MUST work.  SO I am not just a one-trick-pony in all this.  I install one thing at a time, and then verify that everything before that works.  Then I move on to the next.  SciPy, Matplotlab, etc.  (My preference for plotting is gnuplot).  So please understand that I am submitting this answer as a datapoint from a live 24x7 working system in an academic research environment.  This is not a test environment - it is daily production.

Comment: Also, as I alluded to in a comment above, THINK PROFESSIONAL.  These systems are in use by very high-level researchers all over the world.  -->Make sure your boot drive has a clone before you make any major system upgrades.  The `dd` command is quick and easy, and SATA connections are easy.  There is no reason to avoid protecting your system.  Just be careful that at each step you can revert any and all changes that might happen.  Hard rives are a lot less expensive than your time.  (unless you don't think that's true).  Grant funds plus a time crunch should be enough incentive.