# Set default python to 2.7 instead of 3.6 (Anconda & catkin_make)

Tags: python, ros

running python from terminal gives python 3.6, even though the sym link in usr/bin for python is set to 2.7. I also don't see an alias for python installed, when I type alias in the terminal. catkin_make seems to use python 3.6 instead of the 2.7 that it needs...

I only find posts how of how to set ubuntu to default to 3.6. ... what do I do the other way around, to default back to 2.7 after I installed Anaconda?

Edit: [How do I switch back to python2 after Anaconda set python3 as the default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748069/how-do-i-switch-back-to-python2-after-anaconda-set-python3-as-the-default) this worked to get the default python command to call python 2.7 again., but catkin_make still calls the 3.6 python...

Comment: Can you include the output of `type -a python`?

Comment: @Jannis could you please answer your own question and validate it so that it's not an edit of your question? Answers in questions seem bad practice to me and unconvenient to read. Thanks.

Comment: Changing the default python back to calling python 2.7 did not fix my original problem. catkin_make still finds and calls python 3.6

-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /home/username/miniconda3/bin/python

Comment: type -a python

--> python is /usr/bin/python

Comment: Completely deleting miniconda was the first thing that worked.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: VTR as it appears that it's [possible to invoke catkin with a specific python version](https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/issues/166)